# Can ServersAlive monitor a WCF service?

Tags: wcf, monitoring

I have a WCF service that I would like to monitor using ServersAlive.  I would like to be able to check that the service is available from a connection perspective but also be able to call a method on the service to check the purpose of the service is working.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How hard that is probably depends on the binding you're using.  From [ServersAlive](http://www.woodstone.nu/salive/features.asp#monitoring):

> Web Services - Verify the status and
>   content of your web servers (HTTP,
>   HTTPS, MMS, and RTSP). And this by
>   retrieving a page (HTTP(S) GET) or by
>   posting data (HTTP(S) POST). Using a
>   proxy? Not a problem we can handle
>   that. Your webpage is protected with a
>   password (HTTP basic or NTLM
>   authentication)? Again not a problem,
>   we also support that. Servers Alive
>   can also check the validity of your
>   SSL web certificates.

If you're using something simple like wsHTTP, you're probably ready to go out of the box.  However, if you're doing something a more that actually requires the WCF stack, you'll probably have to write some custom code:

## Write your own check - You also have the ability to write custom software to do your own checks through Servers Alive. We already have several examples including:

```
* Virtual machine check in VMWare Server/ESX/GSX
* Mailflow
* IPv6 ping
* *nix diskspace
* *nix processes
* NT eventlog
* Lotus Domino
* and more on this [page][2]
```

Comment: My WCF service is self hosted in a Windows service (as oppsoed to IIS hosted). I have set up a NT Process check on the Windows service which works well. I have now set up an external COM SOAP check to call a method on the WCF service, this method simply returns a number to show the call worked. However this check always returns success even when the service is not running, changing the SOAP result check has no effect, it still thinks the service is UP !!!!

Comment: @Shady - That sounds like you have some implementation specific stuff going on... If you can sort out your external COM SOAP check, you should be good to go.